# drag and drop and Co. with openGL and Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, drag-and-drop, rotation, scaling

I am trying to write a 2D application with openGL (do not ask why, it a test for a stage) where I have a texture I can move around with a drag and drop, rotate or scal with the mouse. My texture is applied on a square.

For these operations, I need to know if I am clicking on the polygon, and the distance and angle between my cursor and the polygon center (which can be moved).
I did not find how to do these with the tutorial I am following does not cover that.

How can I find those 2 informations?

Here is the code :

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>

#ifdef WIN32
    #include <GL/glext.h>
       PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC pGlActiveTexture = NULL;
    #define glActiveTexture pGlActiveTexture
#endif //WIN32

GlWidget::GlWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(QGLFormat(), parent)
{
}

GlWidget::~GlWidget(){}

QSize GlWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(640,480);
}

void GlWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h){

    h = (h<=0?1:h);

    pMatrix.setToIdentity();
    pMatrix.perspective(60.0,(float)w /(float)h,0.1,10);

    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    //glScissor(w*0.8,0,w*0.2,h);
    //glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
}

void GlWidget::initializeGL(){

    #ifdef WIN32
        glActiveTexture = (PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC) wglGetProcAddress((LPCSTR) "glActiveTexture");
    #endif

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    qglClearColor(QColor(Qt::black));


    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, ":/vertexShader.vsh");
    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fragmentShader.fsh");
    shaderProgram.link();

    vertices << QVector3D(-1,-1,-2) << QVector3D(1,-1,-2) << QVector3D(-1,1,-2)
             << QVector3D(-1,1,-2) << QVector3D(1,-1,-2) << QVector3D(1,1,-2);

    textureCoordinates << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(0, 1)
                       << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1);

    texture = bindTexture(QPixmap(":/icone.png"));
    //mMatrix.setToIdentity();


}

void GlWidget::paintGL(){

    //qglClearColor(QColor(Qt::white));
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*qglClearColor(QColor(Qt::black));
    glScissor(this->width()*0.8,0,this->width()*0.2,this->height());
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);*/

    QMatrix4x4 mMatrix;
    QMatrix4x4 vMatrix;

  /*  QMatrix4x4 cameraTransformation;
    cameraTransformation.rotate(25, 0, 1, 0);
    cameraTransformation.rotate(-25, 1, 0, 0);

    QVector3D cameraPosition = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 0, 2.5);
    QVector3D cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 1, 0);

    vMatrix.lookAt(cameraPosition, QVector3D(0, 0, 0), cameraUpDirection);*/

    shaderProgram.bind();
    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix*vMatrix*mMatrix);
    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("texture", 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glActiveTexture(0);

    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", vertices.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");
    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("textureCoordinate", textureCoordinates.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,vertices.size());

    shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("vertex");
    shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");
    shaderProgram.release();

}

void GlWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    if(event->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
        lastPos = event->pos();
    event->accept();
}

void GlWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    if(!event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton)) return;

    int dx = event->x() - lastPos.x();
    int dy = event->y() - lastPos.y();

    if(keysPressed.contains(Qt::Key_Control) && !keysPressed.contains(Qt::Key_Shift)){
        //TODO : implement scaling
    }
    else if(!keysPressed.contains(Qt::Key_Control) && keysPressed.contains(Qt::Key_Shift)){
        //TODO : implement rotate
    }
    else if(!keysPressed.contains(Qt::Key_Control) && !keysPressed.contains(Qt::Key_Shift)){
        //TODO : implement drag
    }

}

void GlWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    keysPressed.append(event->key());

}

void GlWidget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    keysPressed.remove(keysPressed.lastIndexOf(event->key()));
}
```

All the comments are from test I've done and the original tutorial

Comment: That depends on how you implement the canvas in which you display the texture and the texture itself. Qt offers a few different possibilities for that. Please elaborate your implementation.

Comment: Can anybody helps me?